# Is this a range and if yes, how would I access it?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

In my word document I have 2 "sections".
This is a screenshot:

[image]

Unfortunately I can't access the "section" on the right side using this code:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngText As Range
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
Set rngText = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0)
rngText.Collapse wdCollapseStart

With rng.Find
     .Format = False
```

Is this "section" on the right side a range?
And how could I access it with the code above?

Edit: I'm a bit closer now. It's a text field.

I can now access it. The code below shows the text of the text field in a messagebox.
However, it doesn't find the text. I had to remove the "rng" lines because I didn't know what to do with it.

Can anybody help?

Thank you!

```
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Shapes
 With s.TextFrame
 If .HasText Then MsgBox .TextRange.Text

    Dim bDelete As Boolean
    bDelete = False
    'Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngText As Range
    'Set rng = s.Range
    Set rngText = .TextRange
    rngText.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    ' Search-Loop
    With rngText.Find
     .Format = False
     .Text = "{"
     'Search for start tag
     .Execute
     Do While .Found = True
        'Store found position with start tag
       'rngText.SetRange rng.Start, rng.End
       'Reduce search are
       'rng.SetRange rng.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End
       'Search for end tag
       .Execute findText:="}", Forward:=True
       'If none found, exit
       If .Found = False Then Exit Sub
       'Expand found position until tag end
       rngText.SetRange rngText.Start, rng.End
       If bDelete = False Then
        'make the found text bold and give it a certain color
         rngText.Select
         rngText.Font.Bold = True
         rngText.Font.Color = -553582593
         rngText.Text = VBA.Mid(rngText.Text, 2, rngText.End - rngText.Start - 2)
       Else
         'Delete it
         rngText.Delete
       End If
       'Reduce search area until end position
       rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
       'Search for start tag
       .Execute findText:="{", Forward:=True
     Loop
     'rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    End With

 End With
Next
```

Comment: Is that document set up as two `TextColumns`?